# Encoding not active in Save vector layer as

Tags: qgis, geojson, encoding

I've seen some former questions regarding  encoding problems in QGIS, but I'm not able to find any answer for solution. 
I'm a novice in QGIS 2.14(2.18) and want to convert an Esri Shapefile to GeoJSON.

Is there a simple solution out there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94625/geojson-attributes-encoding-limitation. Please expand your question with details from which encoding to which you need to transform, and what problems your output faces.

Comment: I'm not sure of the Shape-file, but I want the GeoJson to be encoded as UTF8.

Comment: GeoJSON **must** be encoded as UTF-8. If your GeoJSON looks weird after saving, you have to sanitize the shapefile by correcting its encoding.